# Array time slots: check for appointment availability by searched datetime and next 2 datetimes

Tags: php, arrays, mapping, filtering

I'm programming an appointment scheduling system. It checks several Google calendars.

**I divided the day (9:00 a.m. - 6:00 p.m.) into 10-minute slots.**

Now I have an array with the respective slots and whether the slot is available or not.

```
[
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 09:00:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 09:10:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 09:20:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 09:30:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 09:40:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 09:50:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 10:00:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 10:10:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 10:20:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 10:30:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 10:40:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 10:50:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 11:00:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 11:10:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 11:20:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 11:30:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 11:40:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 11:50:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 12:00:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 12:10:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 12:20:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 12:30:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 12:40:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 12:50:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 13:00:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 13:10:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 13:20:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 13:30:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 13:40:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 13:50:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 14:00:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 14:10:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 14:20:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 14:30:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 14:40:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 14:50:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 15:00:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 15:10:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 15:20:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 15:30:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 15:40:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 15:50:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 16:00:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 16:10:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 16:20:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 16:30:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 16:40:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 16:50:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 17:00:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 17:10:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 17:20:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 17:30:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 17:40:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 17:50:00', 'available' => 'yes' ]
]
```

My bookable appointment is **30 minutes** long.

How can I check which time slots are available? In this case, there must always be 3 slots in a row without "No". I need the starting time of these 3 slots so that I can make them bookable for clients.

Comment: Why create 10 minute slots if you have 30 minute appointments?

Comment: Because session start times can occur more granularly than 30 minute intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to vary the length of the appointments, you could specify this as the number of slots per appointment.

I propose this more generic approach, which allows for a variable number of slots per appointment, and has a slight optimisation in that the loop will 'skip past' any 'no' entries it finds, avoiding the need to test those entries again:

```
// assumes array of slots is available at $slots

// result - list of available times
$available = [];

// configurable parameter
$slotsPerAppointment = 3;

// main loop    
$startSlot = 0;
while (isset($slots[$startSlot])) {

    $finishSlot  = $startSlot + $slotsPerAppointment - 1;
    if (!isset($slots[$finishSlot])) {
        // not enough slots left in the list - we are finished
        break;
    }

    // test each of the slots between the current $startSlot
    // and $finishSlot, but test in reverse
    // order for performance optimisation
    $found = true;
    for ($testSlot = $finishSlot; $testSlot >= $startSlot; $testSlot--) {
        if ($slots[$testSlot]['available'] == 'no') {

            $found = false;

            // skip past the 'no' slot
            $startSlot = $testSlot + 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($found) {
        $available[] = $slots[$startSlot]['slot'];
        $startSlot++;
    }
}

// show result
print_r($available);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It works great so far, but unfortunately **the last possible** block is missing. Could you check your code again?

2024-01-01 17:30:00 is missing on your example, but should be there as last option to book a 30min appointment

Comment: Ah! Yes, there was an error on the upper bound of the slots being tested.  I updated the answer now

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty trivial to solve, basically you just loop over the 10 min slots, if one is available - and the next two are also available - then that slot is bookable. e.g.

```
$slots = [ // your data... ];
$bookableAppointments = array();

// Loop over each slot, but stop 2 slots before the end
// (the last two cannot be the start of a 30-minute segment)
for ($i = 0; $i < count($slots) - 2; $i++) {
    // Check if the current slot is available ('yes')
    if ($slots[$i]['available'] === 'yes') {
        // Check if the next two consecutive slots are also available ('yes')
        if ($slots[$i + 1]['available'] === 'yes' && $slots[$i + 2]['available'] === 'yes') {
            // Found a slot with the next two consecutive slots also available
            // This slot can be the start of a 30-minute bookable appointment
            $bookableAppointments[] = $slots[$i]['slot'];
        }
    }
}

// Print the list of bookable appointments
print_r($bookableAppointments);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with a suboptimal reference array.  By creating a 2d array of data, you force your code to manually traverse and brute-force check the slots.  Instead, create an associative mapping/lookup array to make searching simpler and more efficient.  Using clear term like "booked" will spare any confusion about the context versus "Yes" and "No".

```
$vacancies = [
    ...
    '2024-01-01 09:40:00' => 'booked',
    '2024-01-01 09:50:00' => 'booked',
    '2024-01-01 10:00:00' => null,
    '2024-01-01 10:10:00' => null,
    ...
];
```

There are 3 possible outcomes. All slots are available, all slots exist, but are not available, and at least one slot occurs outside of business hours.  When all slots exist in your array, return a boolean value; when a slot does not exist in your array, throw an exception (because the searched value is "out of bounds").

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iQ20h))

```
function is30MinuteSessionVacant(array $vacancies, string $dateTime): bool
{
    for ($addMinutes = 0; $addMinutes < 30; $addMinutes += 10) {
        $dateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$dateTime +{$addMinutes} minutes"));
        if (!key_exists($dateTime, $vacancies)) {
            throw new Exception('Proposed time is not within business hours');
        }
        if ($vacancies[$dateTime] !== null) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Execution:

```
$newTests = [
    '2024-01-01 09:50:00',
    '2024-01-01 10:00:00',
    '2024-01-01 15:40:00',
    '2024-01-01 17:40:00',
];

foreach ($newTests as $test) {
    echo "\n$test: ";
    try {
        echo is30MinuteSessionVacant($vacancies, $test) ? 'available' : 'unavailable';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2024-01-01 09:50:00: unavailable
2024-01-01 10:00:00: available
2024-01-01 15:40:00: unavailable
2024-01-01 17:40:00: Proposed time is not within business hours
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$input = [
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 09:00:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 09:10:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 09:20:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 09:30:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 09:40:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 09:50:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 10:00:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 10:10:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 10:20:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 10:30:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 10:40:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 10:50:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 11:00:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 11:10:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 11:20:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 11:30:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 11:40:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 11:50:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 12:00:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 12:10:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 12:20:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 12:30:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 12:40:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 12:50:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 13:00:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 13:10:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 13:20:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 13:30:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 13:40:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 13:50:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 14:00:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 14:10:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 14:20:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 14:30:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 14:40:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 14:50:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 15:00:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 15:10:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 15:20:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 15:30:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 15:40:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 15:50:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 16:00:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 16:10:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 16:20:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 16:30:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 16:40:00', 'available' => 'no' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 16:50:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 17:00:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 17:10:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 17:20:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 17:30:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 17:40:00', 'available' => 'yes' ],
  [ 'slot' => '2024-01-01 17:50:00', 'available' => 'yes' ]
];
```

Filter out the items where 'available' equals to 'yes'. Then loop over these filtered items, and check if the next two indexes exist (note that `array_filter` does not reindex the array it creates, otherwise this approach would not work):

```
$result = [];

$availables = array_filter($input, fn($item) => $item['available'] === 'yes');

foreach ($availables as $index => $available) {
  if (array_key_exists($index + 1, $availables) && array_key_exists($index + 2, $availables)) {
    $result[] = $available;
  }
}

print_r($result);
```

Output (contains all items with 'available' === 'yes', but not the ones with 15:40:00 & 15:50:00, and 17:40:00 & 17:50:00):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 10:00:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 10:10:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 10:20:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 10:30:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 10:40:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 10:50:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 11:00:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 11:10:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 11:20:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 11:30:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 11:40:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 11:50:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 12:00:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 12:10:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 12:20:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 12:30:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 12:40:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 12:50:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 13:00:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 13:10:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 13:20:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 13:30:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 13:40:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 13:50:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 14:00:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 14:10:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 14:20:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 14:30:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 14:40:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 14:50:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 15:00:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 15:10:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 15:20:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 15:30:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 16:50:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 17:00:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 17:10:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 17:20:00
            [available] => yes
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [slot] => 2024-01-01 17:30:00
            [available] => yes
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you. How could I solve it dynamically so that I can set the duration of the appointment to e.g. 10min, 30min, 60min, 120min. So that it also works for different types of appointments.

Comment: @freshwebs You should have added that to your question. This changes it totally.

Comment: I am sorry. Do you still have a solution?

Comment: @freshwebs well that's a math problem. If each slot takes 10 minutes, divide the duration of the appointment (e.g. 30) by 10 and that's is how many indexes from the array you need to look ahead without any "no" as `available.`.